# How to find out who is taking more bandwidth in Squid

Tags: squid

Some of the users are connected to the internet through Squid proxy.
Is there a way to find out who is using the maximum bandwidth from Squid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sqstat. It help me  a lot in the past.

http://samm.kiev.ua/sqstat/

Regards

Comment: This is a great tool, I am also using Squidview which also gives realtime squid activity reports. Thanks Sacx for your help.